# Received fatal alert: bad_certificate when connecting to MySQL >= 8.0.19

Tags: mysql, docker, ssl, jdbc

I try to connect to MySQL instances running in docker via the [MySQL JDBC Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (version 8.0.27) with TLS. While my setup works for all versions prior to 8.0.19, the connection fails for every newer version with the following Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate at 
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) at 
    java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
```

I created the certificates in accordance to the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html):

```sh
# Create CA certificate
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3600 \
-key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem

# Create server certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# server-cert.pem = public key, server-key.pem = private key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
-nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3600 \
-CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem

# Create client certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# client-cert.pem = public key, client-key.pem = private key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
-nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 3600 \
-CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem

openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -out keystore.p12 -name test -CAfile ca.pem -caname root

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeme -destkeypass changeme -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass "" -alias test
```

I created a setup to verify that the problems indeed only happens with MySQL versions >=8.0.19:

```java
public class MySQLTest {

    private @Nullable MySQLContainerSSL mySQLContainerSSL;

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        if (mySQLContainerSSL != null) {
            mySQLContainerSSL.stop();
        }
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {
            "8.0.0",
            "8.0.18",
            "8.0.19",
            "8.0.27"
    })
    void test(final @NotNull String version) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        mySQLContainerSSL = new MySQLContainerSSL(version);
        mySQLContainerSSL.start();

        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("sslMode", "REQUIRED");
        properties.put("useSSL", "true");
        properties.put("user", mySQLContainerSSL.getPassword());
        properties.put("password", mySQLContainerSSL.getUsername());
        properties.put("clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl", new File("src/test/resources/mysql/keystore.jks").toURI().toURL().toString());
        properties.put("clientCertificateKeyStorePassword", "changeme");

        final Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mySQLContainerSSL.getJdbcUrl(), properties);

        assertNotNull(con);
        assertFalse(con.isClosed());
    }


    public static class MySQLContainerSSL extends MySQLContainer<MySQLContainerSSL> {

        public MySQLContainerSSL(final @NotNull String version) {
            super(getAdHocImageName(version));
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            super.stop();
            final String dockerImageName = getDockerImageName();
            DockerClientFactory.instance().client().removeImageCmd(dockerImageName).withForce(true).exec();
        }

        public static @NotNull DockerImageName getAdHocImageName(final @NotNull String mysqlVersion) {
            final String s = new ImageFromDockerfile().withDockerfile(Path.of("src/test/resources/mysql/Dockerfile"))
                    .withBuildArg("MYSQL_VERSION", mysqlVersion)
                    .get();
            return DockerImageName.parse(s).asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mysql");
        }
    }
}
```

The Dockerfile:

```
ARG MYSQL_VERSION
FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}

COPY server-key.pem /var/ssl/server-key.pem
COPY server-cert.pem /var/ssl/server-cert.pem
COPY ca.pem /var/ssl/ca/ca.pem
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
COPY my.cnf /var/lib/mysql-files/my.cnf

RUN chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf \
                     /var/ssl/ \
                    /var/ssl/server-key.pem \
                    /var/ssl/ca/ca.pem \
                    /var/ssl/server-cert.pem && \
    chmod 644 /var/ssl/server-key.pem \
                /var/ssl/server-cert.pem \
                /var/ssl/ca/ca.pem
```

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
ssl_key=/var/ssl/server-key.pem
ssl_cert=/var/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl_ca=/var/ssl/ca/ca.pem
```

My certificates seem to be correct, as they work for older versions, or is there a mistake I did not spot?
Is there a behaviour change from 8.0.18 to 8.0.19 that I am not aware of?
Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Did you find solution to this?